# RoleEnvironment.Changing event doesn't trigger in WorkerRole

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

So, I have Azure project with 3 WebRoles and 1 WorkerRole. In each project I have subscription on RoleEnvironment.Changing and RoleEnvironment.Changed events. In WebRole everything is fine, but in WorkerRole these events don't want to trigger.

Мoreover when I change setting of some WebRole, **WorkerRole is also recycling everytime**

WorkerRole run another x86 proccess inside and script on startup

Azure SDK 1.7 is used

```
<WorkerRole name="MyService" vmsize="Medium" enableNativeCodeExecution="true">
    <Startup>
      <Task commandLine="startup.cmd" taskType="simple" executionContext="elevated" />
    </Startup>
    <Runtime executionContext="elevated" />
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
      <Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
    </Imports>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="8081" />
      <InputEndpoint name="TCPEndpoint" protocol="tcp" port="10101" localPort="10100" />
      <InternalEndpoint name="InternalEndpoint" protocol="http" />
    </Endpoints>
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="StorageConnectionString" />
      <Setting name="TransactionLogsBlobContainer" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
    <LocalResources>
      <LocalStorage name="DiagnosticStore" cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" sizeInMB="8192" />
    </LocalResources>
  </WorkerRole>
```

Does anybody have any idea what could be going on?

Thanks

Comment: This may be obvious, but in the Changing event of the worker, are you setting RoleEnvironmentChangingEventArgs.Cancel to true?  If so, this forces the worker to recycle.  There is only one service configuration file - applicable to all roles, so the worker gets the Changing and Changed events even if the changes are applied only to configuration relevant to a web role.

Comment: problem is that these events are not triggered in worker role according to the logs
yes, there is one file, but when I change setting for one web role, another doesn't react on this

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue and found that changing the `taskType` of the Startup Task from *elevated* to *background* solved my problem.  I'd recommend starting there.

```
<Startup>
  <Task commandLine="startup.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="background"></Task>
</Startup>
```

Comment: I've removed this block at all

`<Startup>
      <Task commandLine="startup.cmd" taskType="simple" executionContext="elevated" />
    </Startup>`


Didn't help..

Answer (score 0):

For worker roles, you must define an **internal endpoint** (even if you don't actually use it), in order to get certain events.

IE, add this to your CSDef:

More details here:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/01/04/responding-to-role-topology-changes.aspx